# Расширение таблицы или связь один ко одному

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица user_card, хранит данные о пользователях сайта. Есть сотрудники, которые как и остальные пользователи регистрируются на сайте и попадают в эту таблицу. Однако кроме стандартных полей, сотрудники могут иметь доп. служебные поля. Эти служебные поля записывать в таблицу user_card или формировать новую таблицу со связью один к одному. При простом добавлении столбцов меня тревожит, что на 40000 строк обычных пользователей служебные столбцы будут не нужны.

Сейчас предполагается что сотрудники могут выступать в качестве клиентов.

Comment: Возможны оба варианта. Поскольку таблица, скорее всего, используется редко и не влияет на производительность, можно поэкономить место и сделать две таблицы.

Comment: Оба варианта имеют право на жизнь. Можно либо упростить код, который выгребает данные из базы (типовой crud, шлёп-шлёп) а значит упрощает разработку; можно сделать ненамного оптимальнее, но немного придётся больше написать. Выбор за вами.